# Подпись об авторе

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Если после названия статьи стоит строка "Текст: Марина Волкова", 
то нужно ли после фамилии ставить точку (как конец предложения)?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, подписью указание авторства не является, поскольку не в конце публикации ставить будете. Во-вторых (это о надобности слова *текст*), если главное в статье не текст, а, допустим, иллюстрации, то только тогда следует акцентировать внимание на авторе текста так, как тут в вопросе.

Под заглавием статьи после имени автора точка не нужна (и необязательна также в конце подписи), хотя в бумажном издании по традиции желательна. Также необходимость точки в конце строки может обосновываться наличием другого знака, как здесь — двоеточия.